# DB2 - Tablespace access is not allowed

Tags: database, db2, database-administration

I am trying to restore a DB2 database to a backup from another database (also DB2). The restore seems to run fine. However, I am receiving the error: Tablespace access is not allowed. I checked the state of the tablespaces and they are stuck in Restore Pending. How do I get them in the correct state? If that's not possible, are there any other suggestions? BTW, I am working in a Windows environment and am using Data Studio for the restore.

Comment: What DB2 version? Are you using automatic storage? If not, are the tablespace container paths the same on the target and the source?

Comment: Did you do a full db restore or a tablespace restore?  And by chance did you do a data "Load" operation?  Check this out for more info: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/c0051301.html

Comment: I am using auto storage, full restore, no data load operation, and the tablespace paths are different.

Comment: Should I be doing a data load operation?

Answer (score 0):

So you tried to do a so called redirected restore as it seems (used the option redirect in the restore command) - right? This means you get the chance to redefine paths during the restore.

The restore ist split up in basically three parts:

1. restore is reading the data and stops
2. lets you redefine the paths
3. restore will finish the restore writing data to the new locations

During Step2 you would see the tablespaces being in restore pending as the restore has started but has not finished yet.
To support you in Step 2 I recommend using

```
restore... redirect generate script <scriptname>
```

which will give you a script with all the possible/necessary commands.

Check out
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006249.html?lang=en

Remember to check the database state afterwards as you might want / need to do a rollfowrds operation as well.

For tablespace states check out following website 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0407melnyk/#rp

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using automatic storage, you'll need to redefine the paths of storage groups that are different in the target. I'm afraid I cannot say how it's done in Data Studio, but there should be a way to accomplish this via the GUI.

In the command line you'll need to do something along these lines. Firstly, determine the storage groups that need redefinition, e.g. by running `db2pd -d yourdb -storagegroups`. The result would look similar to this:

```
Storage Group Configuration:
Address            SGID  Default  DataTag    Name
0x00007F239319BB20 0     Yes      0          IBMSTOGROUP

Storage Group Statistics:
Address            SGID  State      Numpaths  NumDropPen
0x00007F239319BB20 0     0x00000000 1         0         

Storage Group Paths: 
Address            SGID  PathID    PathState    PathName
0x00007F23931C1000 0     0         InUse        /export/db2data
```

Note the names of the storage groups that would have invalid paths on the target system.

Now you can start the restore:

```
db2 restore db yourdb from <path> redirect
```

The command will quickly complete. At this point you will be able to redefine the storage groups:

```
db2 set stogroup paths for <your_stogroup> on '<new_path>'
```

Once you've done that, continue the restore:

```
db2 restore db yourdb continue
```

Finish this off with rollforward if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps:

1. Find the last backup image. and its path
2. Perform redirect Restore:

   ```
   db2 "RESTORE DATABASE dbname  FROM /path TAKEN AT timestamp into NEWDBNAME REDIRECT GENERATE SCRIPT redirectRestore.sql"
   ```
3. Using the VI editor make changes to the redirectRestore.sql file, Change the pathname of the  stogroup paths.
4. Run the .sql file

   ```
   db2 -tvf redirectRestore.sql
   ```
5. Perform Rollforward if required.

   ```
   db2 rollforward db dbname to end of logs
   ```